# Removing multiple request for 'onKeyUp' search

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Is this the correct way of abort multiple requests created when using 'onkeyup' search.

(Note: With multiple request, I refer to sequential request being created for each individual character of a string. Eg: "Hello" create 'H', 'He',...'Hello' - 5 different requests)

```
var insideReq = false;                      /* Initialise to false */
$('#search').keyup( function() {
    var SearchString = $('#search').val();
    if((SearchString.length) >= 3) {
        if(insideReq == true )              /* Check if somebody is inside */
            ajaxReq.abort();                /* If yes, then throw her out */
        insideReq = true;                   /* Inform I am inside */
        var ajaxReq = $.get('search.exec.php', {q: SearchString}, function(ajaxContent) {
            $('#container-list').html("<img src=\"img\\busy.gif\" class=\"busy-indicator\"/>");
            $('#container-list').fadeOut(5);
            $('#container-list').html(ajaxContent);
            $('#container-list').fadeIn(1500);
            insideReq = false;          /* Work done; I am going */
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: This is an issue I've struggled with for a while on my search-as-you-type box.  I just implemented your `insideReq` idea and it seems to be working.  Thanks for the idea!

Answer (score 2):

It looks good. Few code optimization techniques to make your code execute fast.

```
var insideReq = false;                      /* Initialise to false */
$('#search').keyup( function() {
    var SearchString = $('#search').val();
    if((SearchString.length) >= 3) {
        if(insideReq == true )              /* Check if somebody is inside */
            ajaxReq.abort();                /* If yes, then throw her out */
        insideReq = true;                   /* Inform I am inside */
        var ajaxReq = $.get('search.exec.php', {q: SearchString}, function(ajaxContent) {
            $('#container-list')
            .html("<img src=\"img\\busy.gif\" class=\"busy-indicator\"/>");
            .fadeOut(5);
            .html(ajaxContent);
            .fadeIn(1500);
            insideReq = false;          /* Work done; I am going */
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You want this to fire when someone STOPS typing. Create a timer for say, 300ms. Clear and reset the timer on each keystroke. When the timer times out, fire your AJAX request.

Comment: So what I am doing is not the best idea? Timer, though, seems a good concept!